# The difference in pronunciation between ("pre" and "per") / ("dis" and "des")

Tags: pronunciation, writing

How can I distinguish the pronunciation of "pre" from "per" in the beginning of a word?

How can I distinguish the pronunciation of "des" from "dis" in the beginning of a word?

For example:
destiny, desire and distribution. The `de` in the word `destiny` has a different sound than the `de` in the word desire. `di` in the distribution has similar sound to `de` in the desire. 
The question is; 
Are there general guide lines to determine when to use `des` and `dis` in writing besides memorisation? similar question is about `pre` and `per`

Comment: Are you asking about pronouncing these, or about hearing them when pronounced by other people?

Comment: Examples? The difference between *desk* and *disk* should be pretty clear, but the difference between *despondent* and *dispersion* is non-existent for many speakers.

Comment: Please **include the [research](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed)** you've done, or consider if your question suits our [ell.se] site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic.

Comment: What 'variety' of English are you referring to: British, American, Indian, Australian, ...?  I can see that *des* & *dis* may be difficult to distinguish apart at times, But I cannot understand how *pre* & *per* could be confused with one another, at least in British English?

Comment: If you say "despicable" with the first syllable, "des," accented, it sounds quite distinct from "dis." picable. But if you split up the first syllable and say "de" "spicable,"  it comes pretty close to "dis" spicable. Sometimes these prefixes switch over time. For example, the older word perpend, which used "per" to mean thorough, as in peruse, switched to prepend. Even with the new spelling, the word still means mull over or consider carefully, but the change was enough to trick some into using prepend to mean "attach at the beginning." The new meaning is useful and so we have a new word.

Comment: The difference between "per" and "pre" is that the vowel sound comes in the middle in "per" but at the end in "pre".

Comment: @TrevorD I've seen quite a few people write _per(r)ogative_ instead of _prerogative_, or _perscription_ instead of _prescription_. Likely mostly American, but it's not uncommon to pronounce both [pə] in BrE or [pɚ] in AmE.

Comment: I'm not a linguistics expert, but I think you have to look at the sounds that follow the "de." For example, "destiny" has the "-st" sound after the "de", so I think that's why the "e" is pronounced "de" like "Ted." And then the "-sire" in "desire" is like a "phonetic root," (I just made this up) and so we pronounce the "de" as if it were a prefix (e.g., de-escalate, defame, etc.).

Comment: Read this article to get clarity. https://www.spellzone.com/word_lists/list.cfm?wordlist=3918

Answer (score 1):

In the American standard, you should be able to guess the spelling of primary or secondary stressed "des" or "dis" at the beginning of a word.  In "destiny" and "destination", "des" is stressed and has the vowel of "pet", "met" and so on.  In "distant", "disproportionate", "dis" is stressed and has the vowel of "sit", "bit", and so on.

Immediately before a stressed second syllable, however, "des"/"dis" can be stressless and the vowel can vary.  The reduced vowel schwa is always okay, so far as I know, but in "desire", I find also acceptable the "i" of "pit" or the "e" of "scene".  The "i" pronunciation is perhaps a variant form of reduced vowel, and the "e" is probably a spelling pronunciation.

Unstressed "dis", immediately before a stressed syllable, I find varies between schwa and the "i" of "pit", at least when a consonant follows, for instance in "dismay", "disturb", "dispassionate", which I would also attribute to two variant reduced vowels.  When a stressed vowel follows the "dis", as in "disable", the schwa doesn't sound as good, and in "dissect", a tense "ay" diphthong is also possible.

Comment: The varying, reduced vowel is commonly known as a [_schwi_ /ᵻ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English#Reduced_vowels_in_the_close_unrounded_area).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I never heard of "schwi".  I am not referring here to bar-i, which I take to be a high central vowel, but rather to front high lax "i",

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I read over the Wikipedia reference you gave for "schwi".  I think there is some confusion there between what "i"s are front and what ones are central.

Comment: It’s not a bar-i, but a bar-ɪ. The difference between the two is sadly obscured somewhat on Apple computers, whose versions of Helvetica have a bug that displays non-dotted ɪ (as in Turkish) identically to the [_BIT_ vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_near-front_unrounded_vowel). /ᵻ/ is a non-standard, non-precomposed glyph consisting of a barred _BIT_ vowel, and it is used to represent precisely this phoneme which is **not** specified for front-vs-centralness, but varies quite freely between [ə ~ ɪ ~ ɪ̈ ~ i̵], ranging between mid and high, and between central and near-front.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, Well, notation aside, I just don't think American English word final unstressed "-y" is a front vowel (as in "city").  I think it's central, and is homorganic with the [j] offglide.  I don't subscribe to a theory which permits phonemes to have unspecified features, any more than a sound can be partially unspecified.

Comment: My own AmE _-y_ is definitely more front than central (unlike my BrE _-y_, which is more central than front), and I don't see how [j] could be seen as central either. Mostly, though, I don't see any way around accepting underspecified phonemes given the easily verifiable fact that the same phoneme in the same word spoken by the same speaker **does** vary quite a lot. Unless you want hundreds of words to exist in several different phonemic variants (e.g., /roʊzəz ~ roʊzɪz ~ roʊzɪ̈z ~ roʊzɨz/) for many speakers, that is. But that seems rather uneconomic.

Comment: In fact I don't see how you can even operate with the notion of phonemes if you don't accept that phonemes are underspecified—allophony **is** essentially the manifestation of un(der)specified features. A sound can obviously not have unspecified features, but the underlying phoneme almost has to, unless it always maps exactly to one sound only.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I describe variant pronunciations of a phoneme in the same way as any other generative phonologist does -- a phoneme is subject to being modified by various phonological rules.  I'm don't see any difficulty there with assuming that each phoneme has a unique articulation (or, if you like, a unique articulatory target).  // On the centrality of syllable offset [j], just compare it with syllable onset [j], which is front -- you'll probably see what I mean.

Comment: So you just want a phoneme to be specified for all features, and then optionally have those specifications changed by various rules; no quibble with that, that's just a different way of approaching it. I consider feature specification to be immutable, hence my confusion.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, Yes, except phonological rules may or may not be optional, and they may or may not have contextual restrictions, or speed-of-speech or dialectal complications, or ordering constraints.  Generative phonology makes it a complicated world.